# Cucumber Selenium using Excel File as Data Table

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation, cucumber

I am using Cucumber-Selenium and Excel as my Data file, my question is how can I run my feature file multiple time based on the data I have on the Excel. For Example I have 10 rows of data in Excel and wanted to run it one by one, after the first row of data it will move to the next row and execute it.

Feature File:
  Scenario: Login

```
Given I open the browser and access this URL
When I enter the "<Username>" and "<Password>"
Then I am able to login
```

Step Definition:
    public class Login {

```
 WebDriver driver = null;
 String url;        


@Given("^I open the browser and access this URL$")
public void navigateToUrl() throws Throwable{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    url = DataTable.getDataTableValue(0, 2, 2);
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@When("^I enter the \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void enterCredentials(String userName, String password ) throws Throwable {

    userName = DataTable.getDataTableValue(0, 1, 1);
    password = DataTable.getDataTableValue(0, 1, 2);

    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(userName);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);   
}

@Then("^I am able to login$")
public void clickLoginButton() throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
}
```

}

Here is my Data Table(Excel File)

|ID     | UserName  | Password

|ID1    |username1  |password1

|ID2    | username2 | password2

|ID3    | username3 | password3

|ID4    | username4 | password4

Comment: I am also trying to learn Selenium in these days. You should search for the "Apache POI" API. I think that will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already using Excel as my data table but I do not know how to iterate on Cucumber-Selenium.  

Basically the question is instead of using the Example Table in Feature file, I wanted to use excel since I am working on thousands of data.

Comment: @Sachi I don't think it's possible. I am not sure what you want to achieve is it datadriven approach or you just want to abstract data into different excel file. if it's later you can do that with Apache POI but first thing is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to iterate of the content in an Excel sheet you need to implement that in code in the step definition. There is no support for doing it in Gherkin.

Apache POI may be an option when implementing the iteration.

It is important to understand that the purpose of Behaviour-Driven Development, BDD, is communication. Gherkin is one way of communicating. The Gherkin scenarios can be read and understood by almost anyone understanding the problem.

If you have some of the truth in Gherkin and some in Excel you will end up in a situation where you don't use Cucumber and Gherkin for communication but rather as a test tool. This may be ok. But if you use Cucumber as a test tool, there are other tools that may be easier to use. JUnit is one of them.